# I keep receiving a error when trying to give roles

Tags: javascript, function, discord.js

I have a small piece of code that reads from a mongodb database and give them the role in the database

The command requires the user to tag the person they wish to update, what am i doing wrong?

```
msg.mentions.members.first().addRole(msg.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === result[0].MainRank));
```

This is the error:

> ```
> TypeError: msg.guild.roles.find is not a function
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now have to use `msg.guild.roles.cache.find`, since v12 uses Managers.

Comment: I know get this error TypeError: msg.mentions.members.first(...).addRole is not a function

Comment: msg.mentions.members.first().roles.add(...) according to [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager)

Comment: Thank you also much for being so quick and speedy. The problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I have to wait a few mins to select the answer as solved, hope you understand. Harvey